# Using Guzzle in Laravel with POST

Tags: laravel

I want to send a POST request to an external API

Here is my method to call

```
public function recursub(Request $request) {

  $users = User::where('cancel_trial', 1)->get();
  foreach($users as $user) {    
    //dd($user->email);
    $url= 'https://api.paystack.co/subscription';
     $client = new Client();
     $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
       'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
         'Authorization' => 'Bearer sk_test_0994##############',
       ],
       'form_params' => [
        'customer' => '233########',
        'plan' => 'PLN_###########',
     ]
     ]);
     dd($response->getBody());
     //dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
    }


  }
```

But I keep getting this error when I call the endpoint

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (400)
> Client error: `POST https://api.paystack.co/subscription` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "status": false, "message": "Request body could not be parsed. Make sure request body matches specified content-ty (truncated...)

Comment: what laravel version u using?

Comment: Laravel Version 6.90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like that you send wrong request to API.

If you set application/json maybe you should pass parameter in body, not in form params:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
       'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
         'Authorization' => 'Bearer sk_test_0994##############',
       ],
       'body' => json_encode([
           'customer' => '233########',
           'plan' => 'PLN_###########',
     ])
]);
```

Another information that maybe can be helpful is that you can disable exception with ['http_errors' => false] option (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#http-errors).